# KivyMD MDDataTable crash after exceeding the number of "rows_num" on MacOS

Tags: python, datatables, crash, kivy, kivymd

i need help with the MDDataTable. I´m connecting my database to dataTable and on Windows its working. But when i run the same code on my other Laptop with MacOS, its start crashing. I´m including the error masage and the part of code. I already tried reinstal everything but Im running out of ideas. If anyone has come across something similar, I'd be grateful for any advice.

**Code:**

```
def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
    app = MDApp.get_running_app()
    print(app.usernameL)
    print(app.passwordL)
    SQL = "SELECT nazev,mnozstvi,kategorie,datum_uskladneni,ISNULL(datum_odvozu,'neodvezeno') FROM Odpad," \
          "Katalog_odpadu WHERE katalogove_cislo = kod_odpadu AND zdravotnicke_zarizeni_ico = (?) "
    val = app.passwordL
    data = app.cursor.execute(SQL, val)
    hist_data = []
    for row in data:
        hist_data.append(row)

    print(hist_data)
    table = MDDataTable(
        pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
        size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
        use_pagination=True,
        rows_num=5,
        pagination_menu_height='240dp',
        pagination_menu_pos="auto",
        background_color=[1, 0, 0, .5],
        column_data=[
            ("Název", dp(30)),
            ("Váha (g)", dp(30)),
            ("Kategorie", dp(30)),
            ("Uskladněno", dp(30)),
            ("Datum odvozu", dp(30)),
        ],
        row_data=hist_data,
    )
    self.ids['table'].add_widget(table)
```

**Images:**

[Error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPYHG.png)

[Working on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zCFG.png)

Comment: In your error message, did you check the MDIcon's text_color  (`ValueError: None is not allowed for MDIcon.text_color`) ?

Comment: Yes,but in this Screen I dont have any MDIcon which Is build in the MDDataTable when you have more rows of data than parametr "rows_num"

Comment: It was caused by KivyMD version 1.0.0.devs0. When i change it to kivymd-0.104.2  it starts working